# What is the purpose of implementing `Eq`?

Tags: rust

The following rust program outputs the same whether or not `Eq` is implemented. Why bother implementing `Eq` then? Where would implementing `Eq` make a difference?

```
fn main() {
    struct S(i32);
    impl PartialEq for S {
        fn eq(&self, _: &Self) -> bool {
            return false;
        }
    }
    impl Eq for S {} // ?

    let s1 = S(3);
    let s2 = S(4);
    println!("{}", s1 == s1);
    println!("{}", s1 == s2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation from `Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html):

> Trait for equality comparisons which are equivalence relations.
>
> This means, that in addition to `a == b` and `a != b` being strict inverses, the equality must be (for all `a`, `b` and `c`):
>
> - reflexive: `a == a`;
> - symmetric: `a == b` implies `b == a`; and
> - transitive: `a == b` and `b == c` implies `a == c`.
>
> This property cannot be checked by the compiler, and therefore `Eq` implies `PartialEq`, and has no extra methods.

If you implement `Eq` on a type, you're asserting that the reflexive, symmetric, and transitive rules hold for your `PartialEq` implementation. This can't be typechecked, so Rust trusts the programmer to implement `Eq` only if they know it actually satisfies that. This allows certain algorithms to work which wouldn't otherwise work, e.g. `HashMap`.

In other words, `Eq` is how you tell the compiler "my type follows the above rules".

Note: There's no need to type `impl Eq for S {}`, you can just `#[derive(Eq)]` on the declaration of `S`.